# Attribute error about __aexit__ when using 'async with' for an asyncpg connection pool

Tags: python, attributeerror, asyncpg

This is some pertinent code from my `Database` class:

```
class Database:

    pool = None

    def __init__(self, dsn):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.init_async(dsn))

    async def init_async(self, dsn):
        Database.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn)

    async def get_connection(self):
        return await Database.pool.acquire()
```

I thought a static attribute on the class would be an ideal way to store a connection pool, where previously I had one pool per class instance, kinda defeating the object of the pool. I now have an error calling `get_connection` in the following code:

```
async def field(self, sql, *values):
    async with await self.get_connection() as conn:
        return await conn.fetchval(sql, *values)
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Personal\Python Projects\MusicBot\src\bot\bot.py", line 71, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(msg)
  File "D:\Personal\Python Projects\MusicBot\src\bot\bot.py", line 65, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(msg, cls=commands.Context)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 852, in get_context
    prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 797, in get_prefix
    ret = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(prefix, self, message)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 331, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
  File "D:\Personal\Python Projects\MusicBot\src\bot\bot.py", line 61, in prefix
    prefix = await self._fetch_prefix(msg)
  File "D:\Personal\Python Projects\MusicBot\src\bot\bot.py", line 75, in _fetch_prefix
    prefix = await self.db.field("SELECT cmd_prefix FROM guild WHERE guild_id = $1", id)
  File "D:\Personal\Python Projects\MusicBot\src\db\database.py", line 35, in field
    async with await self.get_connection() as conn:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

It looks like my `get_connection` is allergic to `async with`. If I replace `async with` with a plain `await` then stuff works again:

```
async def field(self, sql, *values):
    conn = await self.get_connection()
    return await conn.fetchval(sql, *values)
```

What is wrong here that I get an attribute error for `__aexit__`?

I have been referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626515/15489646) but I cannot "fit" the code structure in the question and the given answer to my scenario.

Comment: You refactored this into this form, right? So what were you `async with` before? It appears that you are now using the wrong type there.

Comment: is the problem solved if you rewrite `get_connection` to not be `async` and directly return whatever `acquire` returns? I think the coroutine that is create by calling a `async` function can't act as a context manager.

Comment: @MegaIng I was using `async with await self.get_connection() as conn:` before. My solution isn't when I rewrite to not be `async`, only when I rewrite not to use `async with`, and you're probably right about `get_connection` not being a context manager, but only some "magical" decorator could make a function act like one.